# Copy binary file in vector

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get familiar with Rust (and learn it) by writing an emulator.
I need to load a file (my rom image) into a vector, that is my emulated ram.

This is my code:

```rust
let image = std::fs::read(filepath).ok().unwrap();
let mut i = 0;
for n in image {
    self.memory[400 + i] = n;
    i += 1;
}
```

memory is a `Vec<u8>` initialized with all zeros (`memory: vec![0; 4*1024]`).
Now with this code I'm ok, it does what I want, but **do I have a better (faster/compact) way to do this?**

Comment: `std::fs::read(filepath)` already returns a `Vec<u8>`.  Only difference that you want that first 400 bytes to be zero ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden I'm using Vector like an array(I know that I should just use array, but I'm doing this to get more comfortable with the language) since the memory of my emulator is fixed at 4K and I'm loading the image at the address 400, so I want the image to be copied from that point on leaving the rest of the memory unchanged (if the other address where 0 they stay zero and so on).

Comment: `Vec::splice` can do the job then: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e469b2026d1c010f88201ac2eae81ef , also it has capability to provide replaced elements if you use the returned iterator.

Answer (score 5):

> do I have a better (faster/compact) way to do this?

Yes. `std::fs::read` is a convenience function that allocates a buffer and reads data into it, growing it as data arrives. Since you already possess a pre-allocated vector and want no resizing, you can use [`BufRead::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) to read directly into it without unnecessary allocations. If your ROM size is fixed you can read the data with a single call to [`read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact):

```
let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open(filepath)?);
file.read_exact(&mut self.memory[400..400 + ROM_SIZE])?;
```

This will avoid unnecessary allocation and copying. Of course, in many cases it won't make a difference in practice, but since your goal is to learn, it makes sense to be aware of the most efficient approach.